# Is there a way how to retrieve, using the Logback API, the Logback path location pragmatically?

Tags: backlog

I have a Java/C++ application, the java part uses Backlog and I need to put the C++ part log files into the same path location as Backlog. Is there a way how to retrieve, using the Logback API, the Logback path location pragmatically (the fileNamePattern value in logback.xml) ?

Thanks